# What is the equivalent of C:/ in mysql using linux?

Tags: mysql

I have this code but I can' figure out how to change the C:/ drive to an equivalent  of linux.  Below is the code:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/CountryLanguage.txt' FROM CountryLanuage;
```

I have tried doing '/student', '/home', '/usr', and just plain '/CountryLanguage'  I am not sure what to do.  Can someone please help me?
Thanks,

Comment: It depends on how you would save the file. the root of the filesystem in linux is `/`

Comment: The problem is most likely that you don't have write access to the directories you're trying to use. You need to pick a directory that you own and have write access to.

Comment: I have to do this while I am in mysql.  I have write permissions to all of these files.  I have tried all the files that I know I have, which is not many, and none of them are working. I have tried 'chmod 777 /(FileName)' and it is still not working.

Comment: Do you or MySQL have write permissions to the folders? What folder did you change permissions for? I belive you'll have to change permissions for it's parents to. I.e: giving write permissions in /var/lib/ wont work since /var/ dosen't allow you to write. I belive. And also make sure that **MySQL** has write permissions, not your user. @TaraMallakJohnson

Answer (score 1):

Well, this depends on where you would like to save the file. 
If you would like to save it in for example "/student" you'll first have to create this folder in the root folder "/". Creating a folder is done by typing:

```
cd /
mkdir students
```

Once the directory is created you can make sure it's there by typing:

```
ls /
```

Which display all the files and folders in /.

```
ls /students
```

Displays all the files in the /students folder.

Since this is in the Linux root you'll have to change the permissions for the folder so that MySQL can write to it. This by typing:

```
chmod 777 /students
```

You shall only use 777 for testing since this allows everyone to read, write and execute in that folder but i advise using this to make sure it's not the permissions causing an error.

**EDIT:**
If you **don't** have root access to the system you should try saving your file to "/var/lib/mysql/" where MySQL can write.

Comment: It's unlikely that the person asking has root access to the system.

Comment: Why is that unlikely? A lot of people manage their own webservers, especially for development.

Comment: The level of knowledge implied by the question strongly suggests that this is not someone who would manage their own webserver. Also, that they try to use a directory called "students" suggests that this is a university/school server.

Comment: And I hope that these people know the equivalent of C:\ on their linux webserver.

Comment: I don't know the equivalent of c directory and that is what I'm asking about.  And yes I am a student for Web Development  and I am the root user.    Please don'the treat those that are asking for help like they are all incompetent.  That really helps no one. And that is what this website is here for.  Thanks.

Comment: I have absolutley no idea what you are talking about, obviously you've missunderstood. I'm not trying to be impolite, I'm trying to help you. C:/ is equal to / in Linux systems. Good luck. @TaraMallakJohnson

Comment: It wasn't u that said anything rude, it was teetrinker that said "these people".

Comment: I have tried the / and it doesn't work.  So u r saying that I have to change the writing permissions but I have not done that b4 and don't know how 2.

Comment: My answer explains this. Have you created and located the folder you want to save your file? In that case, where? 

The `chmod 777 /(folder)` changes the permission so that everyone can read, write and excecute in that folder. This eliminates permissions causing the problem.